# How to install Feitian R502 driver on Windows 10 IoT

Tags: raspberry-pi2, drivers, windows-10-iot-core, smartcard-reader

I have **Raspberry Pi 2 B** with **Windows 10 IoT**. I try to run Universal Windows Platform which use SmartCardReader. When I connect **Feitian R502 Dual** reader it's not found as CardReader. I found indicator description:

> USB data transfer – red color
>
> ```
> No      explanation              Status
> 1     USB enumerating               1Hz flashing
> 2     USB enumerated                 Turn on
> 3     Firmware checksum failure     4Hz flashing
> ```
>
> Contact card – Blue color
>
> ```
> No      explanation              Status
> 1       No card                     Turn off
> 2     Card inserted                 Turn on
> 3     Data transfer                 flashing
> ```
>
> Contactless card－Green color
>
> ```
> No      explanation             Status
> 1       No card                     Turn off
> 2     Card inserted                 Turn on
> 3     Data transfer                 flashing
> ```

I have red indicator flashing with freq 1Hz. Others indicators flash properly. Can anyone help mi with configuration/installation? I found how to install drivers: [link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/driverlab2) and [link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/driverlab3) but i have't sources of proper drivers.

Comment: Based on [this document](https://github.com/FeitianSmartcardReader/R502#driver), driver already integrated into Windows 10 system. Have you tried on PC with Windows 10?

Comment: Yes, with Windows 10 PC works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some messages with Feitian Support. We came to conclusion that Microsoft **didn't deliver usb ccid drivers** for Windows 10 IoT core. Finally communication with SmartCardReader connected to Windows 10 IoT core device is **possible using HID reader** (W10 IoT has driver). It's possible but it's not support classes from Windows.Device.Smartcard namespace.